# Custom VBA function using for loop & ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to right my own function and need some help with looping through a set of data. The code I have posted below allows me to set two variables "CFirstCell" and "CLastCell" (this is only a part of what the overall function will actually do). This will return an address (an example of this being: CFirstCell:"$I$4" & CLastCell:"$AL$4").

I now want to take these two variables and loop through the cells between them (within the sheet called "Client Configuration") and then take those values that are not blank and store them all "AllCodes". Once I have all those values stored in the array "AllCodes", I want to loop through that array and print out a message with each value. How can I do this?

An example of this would be to loop through the range I4:AL4 and then return a message box that would print out the values in cells I4:P4 because they are the only ones that aren't blank.

```
Public Function GETHOLDINGS(ClientId, Category, CategoryValue, DisplayValueAs) As String

    Dim ClientName As String
    Dim ReportingType As String    

    Dim CFirstCell As String
    Dim CLastCell As String

    Dim AllCodes As String

    ClientName = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Client Configuration").Range("Client_Config_Table[[#All],[Client Name]]"), _
    WorksheetFunction.Match(1, Sheets("Client Configuration").Range("Client_Config_Table[[#All],[ID]]")))

    ReportingType = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Client Configuration").Range("Client_Config_Table[[#All],[Portfolio Reporting Type]]"), _
    WorksheetFunction.Match(1, Sheets("Client Configuration").Range("Client_Config_Table[[#All],[ID]]")))

    CFirstCell = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Client Configuration").Range("Client_Config_Table[[#All],[C1]]"), _
    WorksheetFunction.Match(1, Sheets("Client Configuration").Range("Client_Config_Table[[#All],[ID]]"))).Address
    CLastCell = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Client Configuration").Range("Client_Config_Table[[#All],[C30]]"), _
    WorksheetFunction.Match(1, Sheets("Client Configuration").Range("Client_Config_Table[[#All],[ID]]"))).Address

End Function
```

Comment: Don't use the cell addresses. Just build up a `Range` of the two.

Comment: ^ You can use `Range.Find` here instead of `Index/Match`.

Comment: Why do you have `ClientId`, `CategoryValue`, `DisplayValueAs` like function input parameters if you do not use them at all? Your `GETHOLDINGS` function should return a string, but it does not return anything. Since `Category` comes from the function parameters and you do  not process anything to change it, what do you expect  from `Select Case` to return? Can you better explain (in words) what you intend to do? Your code does not make me understood too much and I am not able to help in this circumstances...

Comment: @FaneDuru I haven't built out the full function yet so please ignore the extra code at the moment. I'm trying to pull in a few base variables first before I start developing out what the parameters will do.

Comment: @BigBen Can you provide an example of how I would reformat the code to Range.Find?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, please. It should do what (I understood from your words part) you need. In order to understand how it works, I created a sub able to test it:

```
Sub testGETHOLDINGS()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, CFirstCell As String
    Dim AllCodes As Variant, El As Variant, CLastCell As String
    CFirstCell = "$I$4" 'determine it as you whish or give more
                        'details to find a different way
    CLastCell = "$AL$4" 'determine it as you whish
    Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
    Set rng = sh.Range(CFirstCell & ":" & CLastCell) 'build the range
    AllCodes = GETHOLDINGS(sh, rng) 'use the function to build the
                                    'array of non empty cells value
    If AllCodes = Empty Then Exit Sub 'if rng has more then one row
    For Each El In AllCodes
        Debug.Print El 'it returns in Immediate Window all elements
    Next
End Sub

Private Function GETHOLDINGS(sh As Worksheet, rng As Range) As Variant
  Dim arrC() As String, arrRng As Variant, i As Long, lngEmpty As Long
  Dim nonEmpty As Long, k As Long, rngRow As Long

  rngRow = rng.Cells(1, 1).Row 'determine the range row
  If rng.Rows.count > 1 Then 'stops if rang has more the 1 row
    MsgBox "This function works for one single row range!"
    GETHOLDINGS = Empty: Exit Function
  End If
  'determine how many empty cells are in rng
  lngEmpty = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells.count
  nonEmpty = rng.Cells.count - lngEmpty 'non empty cells number
  ReDim arrC(nonEmpty + 1) 'redim the array to the appropriate value
  arrRng = rng.Value 'pass the range values in arrRng array
  For i = 1 To rng.Cells.count 'iterate between the array elements
    If sh.Cells(rngRow, i).Value <> Empty Then
        'load in the array the non empty cells
        arrC(k) = sh.Cells(rngRow, i).Value: k = k + 1
    End If
  Next i
  If arrC(0) <> Empty Then GETHOLDINGS = arrC ' return the array
End Function
```

Comment: I don't want to hard code the values of I4 and AL4, these values are being returned dynamically from the index match that I am running.

Comment: Do you need a function to return (in an array) the non empty cells of that specific range, like I understood from your question? If yes, the above function does exactly that. Do you need something else? If yes, please define what...

Comment: @Gil:  The above function does exactly what you says! If you can not understand that, I cannot help you. Sorry... Everything is in variable `AllCodes`.